# RSA_sign and RSACryptoProvider.VerifySignature

Tags: c#, cryptography, openssl, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm trying to get up to speed on how to get some code that uses OpenSSL for cryptography, to play nice with another program that I'm writing in C#, using the Microsoft cryptography providers available in .NET.

More to the point, I'm trying to have the C# program verify an RSA message signature generated by the OpenSSL code. The code that generates the signature looks something like this:

```
// Code in C, using the OpenSSL RSA implementation

char msgToSign[] = "Hello World";     // the message to be signed
char signature[RSA_size(rsa)];        // buffer that will hold signature
int slen = 0;                         // will contain signature size

// rsa is an OpenSSL RSA context, that's loaded with the public/private key pair

memset(signature, 0, sizeof(signature));

RSA_sign(NID_sha1
      , (unsigned char*)msgToSign
      , strlen(msgToSign)
      , signature
      , &slen
      , rsa);

// now signature contains the message signature
//  and can be verified using the RSA_verify counterpart
// .. I would like to verify the signature in C#
```

In C#, I would do the following:

- import the other side's public key into an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` object
- receive the message and it's signature
- try to verify the signature

I've got the first two parts working (I've verified that the public key is loading properly because I managed to send an RSA encrypted text from the C# code to the OpenSSL code in C and successfully have it decrypted)

In order to verify the signature in C#, I've tried using the: VerifySignature method of the RSACryptoServiceProvider but that didn't work. And digging around the internet I was only able to find some vague information pointing out that .NET uses a different method for generating the signature than OpenSSL does. So, does anybody know how to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Since there was a request, here's the C# side of things..

```
byte[] receivedSignature;
// ....
// receivedSignature is set to the byte array generated by the OpenSSL side
//   I've verified this much is working correctly

// I use my utility to parse a PEM file and extract the other side's public key
//   also, verified to be working correctly - the public key is good.
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = MyPEMLoader.LoadFromFile("publicKey.pem");

string msgToVerify = "Hello World";
byte[] msgBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);  // other side uses ASCII, so do the same
bool verified = rsa.VerifyHash(msgBytes, "SHA1", receivedSignature);

// verfied is false.. verfification failed!
```

Comment: Any solution to this? I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you showed your C# code. I think it should be something like:

```
    string msg = ...;
    byte[] localData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
    bool ok = rsa.VerifyHash(localData, "SHA1", receivedhash);
```

And of course I'm just guessing the UTF-8 part. Might be ASCII as well.

Edit: Here is the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.verifyhash.aspx). The example seems to do it different, localData is hashed first.

```
hashedData = hash.ComputeHash(signedData);
return rsaCSP.VerifyHash(hashedData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signature);
```

Comment: Thanks @Henk, please see my edit.  This is pretty much what I was doing but apparently it doesn't work like this. Have you successfully tested this code with an RSA signature generated with OpenSSL?

Comment: No, I haven't used OpenSSL. Best check the MSDN link, I copied the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your pem utility, this is not required and use

```
 var cert = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/App_Data/PublicKey.pem"), "");
var rsaCryptoIPT = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
if (!rsaCryptoIPT.VerifyData(data, sha1, signature))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid signature from bank ");
```

If this does not help can you post pem file reader code.